# Copy body of outlook mail to a text file

Tags: c#, outlook

Is there any way to copy email body of an outlook mail to a text file using c#. I am not getting a way to do this

Comment: Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx#17.2 Parsing text from a message body)

Comment: I want it using C#. The link which you shared is for VB implementation

Comment: Use a VB to C# parser. The link is to provide you information on how it can be done. You need to write your own code!

Comment: @Raushan The answer to your question is: Yes, it is possible to copy the text of an email to a text file with C#. How to do that is an exercise left to you—Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. After you've put in reasonable effort, come back to us with specific questions about where you're stuck. If you have more questions, take a look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

when using Interop this will help to save the whole mail as Text file. Then you can parse the file to get the body part and save it.

```
mailItem.SaveAs(@"c:\path\to\save\mail.msg", Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olTXT);
```